# ModuleNotFoundError while creating gym installed from github

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I was trying out to create a custom gym for [Kaggle hungry geese competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/hungry-geese). I created one and committed [here](https://github.com/Mahesha999/gym-hungrygeese). I installed it with command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Mahesha999/gym-hungrygeese.git
```

and then tried to create a gym:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('gym_hungrygeese:hungrygeese-v0')
```

But it gave following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in spec(self, path)
    108             try:
--> 109                 importlib.import_module(mod_name)
    110             # catch ImportError for python2.7 compatibility

7 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module(name, package)
    126             level += 1
--> 127     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    128 

/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym_hungrygeese'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-8fba512a2b25> in <module>()
      1 import gym
----> 2 env = gym.make('gym_hungrygeese:hungrygeese-v0')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)
    143 
    144 def make(id, **kwargs):
--> 145     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
    146 
    147 def spec(id):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
     87         else:
     88             logger.info('Making new env: %s', path)
---> 89         spec = self.spec(path)
     90         env = spec.make(**kwargs)
     91         # We used to have people override _reset/_step rather than

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in spec(self, path)
    110             # catch ImportError for python2.7 compatibility
    111             except ImportError:
--> 112                 raise error.Error('A module ({}) was specified for the environment but was not found, make sure the package is installed with `pip install` before calling `gym.make()`'.format(mod_name))
    113         else:
    114             id = path

Error: A module (gym_hungrygeese) was specified for the environment but was not found, make sure the package is installed with `pip install` before calling `gym.make(

)`
```

What I am missing?

PS: you can find the colab notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zh9XJnwAD_jugaoF8tP_2vCiDtHubls1?usp=sharing).